# Loop in JSON response after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using following ajax which returns JSON data:-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "####",
    data: "####",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
       ????
    }
});
```

Here is returned JSON data, I see this when mouse hover on function(data) in chrome developer tool:-

```
d: "[{"name":"deepak","arrivalTime":"675"},{"name":"sumit","arrivalTime":"690"},{"name":"satish","arrivalTime":"1740"}]"
```

Now I would like to loop and display name and arrivalTime, please help me on this.

I tried following ways, none of them worked:-

## 1.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var obj = data[i];
  for (var key in obj) {
    var attrName = key;
    var attrValue = obj[key];
  }
}
```

## 2.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    console.log(obj.name);
    console.log(obj.arrivalTime);
}
```

## 3.

```
$.map(data.d, function (item, data) {
    console.log(item.name);
    console.log(data.name);
    console.log(item.arrivalTime);
    console.log(data.arrivalTime); //tried all luck :)
});
```

## 4.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].name);
    alert(data[i].arrivalTime);
})
```

## 5.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.name);
    alert(item.arrivalTime);
})
```

Comment: What error you getting in console with above methods?

Comment: [No. 2 works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/XX5zL/) at the very least.

Comment: Number 1 works perfectly fine too. - See [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LTb3K/) You have to give some more information. Are you getting any errors/warning in the debugger console? Also when you do a `console.log(data)` is the object a valid JSON object?

Comment: Isn't your data a STRING ? You should return a JSON from your end point, not a STRING.

Comment: jQuery will parse the data automatically if the JSON dataType is set. This shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: True, but its data looks like a string... =/

Comment: Yeah, and that's what doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe with a picture of the console ?

Comment: 2nd works fine for me..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are getting, but it seems that your data is returned as an object d.

```
var dataArray = data.d;
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
   var name = dataArray[i].name;
   var arrivalTime = dataArray[i].arrivalTime;
};
```

BTW, to me, your string array looks like a string, you might want to parse it.

```
var dataArray = JSON.parse(data.d);
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
   var name = dataArray[i].name;
   var arrivalTime = dataArray[i].arrivalTime;
};
```

Comment: To the person who mark it down, Please check before you mark it down. This is the fiddle that simulate what he is asking http://jsfiddle.net/HMahP/

Comment: thanks nightingalez for the help. after JSON.parse(data.d) it worked. Just a quick help, how to get each set one by one. For example, in first loop it should show {"name":"deepak","arrivalTime":"675"} and in second loop it should show {"name":"sumit","arrivalTime":"690"} and so on. This will be a great help from you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var d = '[{"name":"deepak","arrivalTime":"675"},{"name":"sumit","arrivalTime":"690"},{"name":"satish","arrivalTime":"1740"}]';
d = JSON.parse(d);
for (i =0; i< d.length; i++) {
  alert(d[i].name+"--"+d[i].arrivalTime);
}
```

Comment: Can you try this link. Its getting.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/VtVFB/615/